# How do I search softlayer api for a list of servers by os version

Tags: api, version, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have my API Key generated. I only use Windows as my OS of choice. I would like to query the SL Portal for all machines (Bare Metal and Virtual) and sort by OS Version. IE. 2008 Standard vs. 2008 Data Center.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get virtual guests and bare metal servers making a single call, try the following Rest requests.

**To get Virtual Guests:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"billingItem":{"children":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"*=2008 Standard"}}}}}}&objectMask=mask[operatingSystem.softwareDescription.name]

Method: Get
```

**To get Bare Metal Servers:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectFilter={"hardware":{"billingItem":{"children":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"*=2008 Standard"}}}}}}&objectMask=mask[operatingSystem.softwareDescription.name]

Method: Get
```

You just need to replace **$user**, **$apiKey** and **2008 Standard** (Keep *= at the start)

Comment: Silly newbie question. Where do I run this? I can VPN into SL and log onto Windows computers, no Linux. What is a rest command?

Comment: You can use [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for chrome, also to get more information about rest: See [Rest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest)

Comment: Ok, I assume you mean this rest - http://rest.elkstein.org/ but even knowing what it is, does not help me use the command. Windows (IE) says it can't find the command. It wants me to check the spelling and try again. The HTTPS user:api@softlayer looks correct though...

Comment: Ok, so turns out IE just sucks. I pasted the same code in Firefox and got an XML output!

Comment: Output shows this: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      Any way to get this in a readable, maybe csv or excel format?

Comment: Using the explorer as you did, it's only possible to get the result in json or xml, if you want to get in csv or excel format, it's necessary to use a programming language, see the following link to get available programming languages supported by SoftLayer:
[SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)